# 32bit int & 64bit double with Lua

Tags: lua

Is there going to be a problem if I use 32bit "int" as Lua_Integer and 64bit "double" as Lua_Number?

According to the documentation, it says that the default is 64bit "long long" and 64bit "double", and it also says that it is free to change the real types of  Lua_Integer and Lua_Number by editing luaconf.h. But my concern is that it is only considering the case where Lua_Integer and Lua_Number is both 32bits, so in my case, might fail on the casts between those two types.

The reason why I can't use "long long" is because the host program's language is not capable of 64bit integers.

Should I give up and use 32bit for both integer and double?

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask this also in the Lua mailing list.

Comment: Beware of low precision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limits_on_integer_values

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that.